# How can I suppress viewing / listing all file types EXCEPT html files using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, directory, filelist

Basically I want to go beyond simple "`Options +Indexes`" display on a server, set using the `.htaccess` file.

I ONLY want to see `.html` files in a given directory, and suppress display of ALL OTHER file types.

Why? I am happy to show directory listing pages on a testing server, so a client can select different page design versions, for instance...

BUT I would prefer they just see the '`.html`' files on the directory listing, NOT any other image files, favicon files and so on.

Any clues much appreciated, not that familiar with `.htaccess` possibilities.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use `IndexIgnore` carefully .
For example ,if you put the following code :

```
Options +Indexes
IndexIgnore  *
```

The directory listing will be on but nothing will be shown so the use of `IndexIgnore` is to hide what you want when directory listing is done .

Another example is to do the following :

```
Options +Indexes
IndexIgnore  *.php *.jpg *.png  *.txt *image
```

The code above will hide all files with these extensions as well as image folder  , so you should exclude all folderes and files that you don't want them to be shown  , `.html`  files are not listed above so,they will be shown.

Comment: glad to help , wish all the best